# How can I change branch default to master default

Tags: branch, default

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8bSB.png)
i dont know how to change default branch to default master

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Code and Automation -> Default Branch

More details here:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Comment: this repository me50/username is not mine. I can't change default branch. do u have any git command or something to change default branch